# Change sparse attribute from an .iso file on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, sparseimage, sparsefile

I have few very large .iso files in my computer altogether about 1TB. All of them are sparse files and i want to remove the sparse flag/attribute from them, is there a way how to do it? Maybe some application or so?

I know when i copy the file the flag is removed, but copying 1TB of files is kind of complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control whether the file is set as sparse or not by running (from an elevated command prompt) `fsutil sparse setflag <filename> 0|1`

To turn off the sparse setting, run:

```
fsutil sparse setflag YOURFILENAMEHERE 0
```

To turn it back on, run:

```
fsutil sparse setflag YOURFILENAMEHERE 1
```

and to query it:

```
fsutil sparse queryflag YOURFILENAMEHERE
```

I found this by trial and error and a [search on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757759%28v=WS.10%29.aspx#w2k3tr_ntfs_tools_naua) - I don't go around setting or unsetting sparse files so I can't speak to any risks from doing this, other than the file(s) will take up much more actual space than they might have otherwise.